# Image Enlarger Script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking for one of those scripts that when you click a Thumbnail, it makes the picture englarge. I tried searching Google using a lot of terms, but cant find any.

Where do I get these?

Comment: Impossible! What Google version do you use? ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe one of these are what you are looking for.

http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/

http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/

Comment: I wrote a lightbox that'll animate the enlargement of the image to the centre of the page when you click on it - see https://github.com/khoomeister/jquery-lightbox

Comment: This is perfect. I am trying to use the one from the first link but it is breaking the other JQuery stuff in the template already. I have upvoted your answer but I will wait to hear back from you before accepting it. This is what my <head> section looks like, do you have any idea? http://pastebin.com/DH6wWqKc

Comment: When I add the code from that first one, the buttons from the other JQuery script disappear.

Answer (score 1):

They're called lightboxes, if you search google again, I'm sure you'll find a lot.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know they had a name

Answer (score 0):

i would use some very simple javascript:

your img tag in html file:

```
<img src="lala.alal" id="getbigger" onClick="grow()" />
```

your javascript:

```
function grow() {
width = document.getElementById('getbigger').width;
height = document.getElementById('getbigger').height;
width = width*[INSERT GROWTH RATIO HERE];
height = height*[INSERT GROWTH RATIO HERE];
document.getElementById('getbigger').height = height;
document.getElementById('getbigger').width = width;
}
```

of course you could just use [jQuery animate tools](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

a good demo of jQuery animate with changing height and width is at [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_animation) w3schools page.

Comment: Using a pre-made lightbox plugin is better, especially if they're free ;)

Comment: hmm... maybe :p i'm just stuck on do it yourself mode after my bookmarklet